# inline::java and strawberry perl

Tags: java, perl, cpan, perl-module

I Tried to install this module : Inline::Java with strawberry perl 5.10 i get the below error message :

```
dmake:  Error code 129, while making '..\blib\arch\auto\Inline\Java\JNI\JNI.dll'
dmake.EXE:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
  PATL/Inline-Java-0.53.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.EXE -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 PATL/Inline-Java-0.53.tar.gz                 : make NO
```

where the following environent varialbes are defined as below :

PERL_INLINE_JAVA_J2SDK =C:\jdk1.7.0
PERL_INLINE_JAVA_JNI =1

also all the jdk1.7.0 subdirectories are added to the path environment variable .

Could someone have a hint what could be this error?

and how can i correct it if possible ?

Comment: You may consider joining the Inline mailing list to ask the question in a forum frequented by Inline users/developers.  inline@perl.org.  See http://lists.perl.org for details.

Answer (score -3):

The issue is covered in this FAQ:
[Strawberry Perl - Win32 Wiki](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Strawberry_Perl)

Please edit you post title to indicate you want help with an build issue.

Comment: Point out which part of the FAQ applies. Quote it.

Comment: I agree with daxim. What part of the FAQ applies?